# Usage of JSON.stringify() breaks page without errors in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

Usage of JSON.stringify() breaks page without errors in console

EDIT: I read about jquery plugin jquery-json, I tried that with the same result.

```
var bookmarkParams = {"id":"123456"};

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://service',
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        // some headers
    },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(bookmarkParams),
    success: successCallback,
    error: errorCallback
});
// successCallback & errorCallback are defined functions
```

any ideas why this might be?

If i don't use JSON.stringify() then the page does not break but my AJAX request won't function correctly when passing my data to the server.

Comment: Maybe should be `JSON.stringify(bookmarkParams)` instead of `JSON.stringify(params)` ?

Comment: Should `params` be `bookmarkParams`? What does "breaks page" mean? Please post a specific error.

Comment: What browser does this break in?  Some browsers don't have JSON integrated, or there compatibility mode (grr, IE 10/11) makes it unavailable.

Comment: How are you receiving the json? ajax reply? or set var?

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: What do you mean by "my AJAX request won't function correctly"? Is the request sent to the server? If so, what does the server return?

Comment: All else being equal, that code will throw a reference error because `url` is not defined. (And once that is fixed it will throw one for `params`, `successCallback` and then `errorCallback`). So either you are wrong about there being no errors, or you could do with adding more information to the question. Certainly you should look at the Net tab as mentioned above.

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using. Which browser + version are you using?

Comment: jquery 1.10, newest chrome

Comment: 1.10 is really old. Is upgrading an option?

Answer (score -1):

What is params? Don't you mean bookmark params?

try this...

var bookmarkParams = '{"id":"123456"}';

then change params to bookmarkParams

Comment: Was the question edited? `bookmarkParams` is an object, not a string.